# Measuring a Buffer

Tags: distance, buffer, units

If I create buffers around coordinate points using a linear unit of measurement, is the distance I input the radius around the point or diameter? For example, if I input 800 meters, will it form a buffer around the point with a radius of 800 meters?

Also, should I be concerned about using the unit meters in the coordinate system GCS_North_American_1983, which uses an angular unit of degrees?

Comment: What software are you using? You should mention this in the question and also add a tag with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using 800 meters as your input will form a buffer around your point that has a radius of 800 meters. I would, however, convert your data frame to a Projected Coordinate System using meters just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Former--the distance you enter is in radius. Maybe you have a measure tool you can test this with.